# wait-for-it.sh not fully working for Pentaho Server (8080 is up before server is ready for login)

Tags: docker, pentaho, kettle

Background:

1. I have deployed Pentaho Server in Docker
2. I have implemented wait-for-it concept to wait for a service at host/port before starting docker services. [like this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)
3. Everything works fine in principle.

Problem:

1. My docker service(s) wait for a particular host/post to be available.
2. Then they start
3. **Exception**: Pentaho Server where it prints

`wait-for-it.sh: pentaho_server:8080 is available after 0 seconds`

meaning as soon as `pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh` is executed, it is starting port 8080 (before server is up).

---

Pentaho Server: Client-Server module for Pentaho-Kettle ETL Tool [read more](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/Installation/Manual)

Comment: you need to setup a custome script to check if the server is up ....

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but is my understanding of `wait-for-it` flawed or is pentaho not designed correctly?

Comment: wait-for-it is just try to see if the server:port is reachable but will not wait till the server is functional. therefore it will works well with mysql images that the port is opened after the server is running

Comment: ok understood. thanks